# Problem with polynomials and using the lemma if $P(x_0)=0$, then $P(x) = (x-x_0)Q(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and that has roots $1997$ and $2010.$ Assume also that $|P(2005)| < 10.$ What integer values can $P(2005)$ have?

I was given a hint to use the following lemma:

If $P(x_0)=0$, then $P(x) = (x-x_0)Q(x)$, however I couldn't figure this out even with this. What's the name of this lemma I would like to see the proof and more about it?

Comment: This is the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials. You could look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472142/euclidean-algorithm-for-polynomials) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor)

Comment: Hint: What happens when you plug in $x=2005$ to $(x-1997)(x-2010)R(x)$?

Comment: @rogerl Could you elaborate, is the problem equivalent in finding the gcd somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since both $1997$ and $2010$ are roots, we have
$$P(x) = (x-2010)(x-1997)Q(x)$$
for some polynomial $Q$. Then
$$P(2005) = (2005-2010)(2005-1997)Q(2005) = -40Q(2005).$$
Now use the condition that $|P(2005)|<10$.

Comment: From here I get that $|-40Q(2005)| < 10$ this would imply that $-10 < -40Q(2005) < 10$, hence $\frac{1}{4} < Q(2005) < -\frac{1}{4}$. This is a contradiction?

Comment: No, it means that $\frac{1}{4} > Q(2005) > -\frac{1}{4}$, forcing $2005$ to be a root as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you know that there exists $Q_1(x)$, with integer coefficients, such that $P(x)=(x-1997)Q_1(x)$.

Then $P(2005)=(2005-1997)Q_1(1997)$ is divisible by $8$.

On the other hand, there is $Q_2(x)$, with integer coefficients, such that $P(x)=(x-2010)Q_2(x)$.

Can you finish?